# Why does a custom sound assigned by setting public soundURI to Android Notification Channel work and not work sometimes?

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I am looking for ways to allow marketers to be able to send notification with custom sound to their apps.
Android Oreo ((8), Api 26) onwards, `[Notification Channel](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/channels)` is where you set the sound instead of notification builder.

The way to add sound is to pass in the URI of the sound to the channel when the channel is being created.

`notificationChannel.setSound(soundUri, audioAttributes);`

What I saw so far on the web is that the uri has to be a location - usually of sound file which is stored in  `app > res > raw` directory.

Now that it takes in URI, I tried hosting a .mp3 file on s3 bucket, and made it public. Taking that link, when i passed that to create channel, I was able to play that sound! A remote sound sent as a payload being used live -right when notification arrives. Felt so good. However, when testing on multiple devices, I saw its not the case.

It is consistently working on my Pixel 6 Api 33 device.
Also runs on my emulator - Pixel 5 with Api 33.
But DOES NOT run on my Motorola g play actual device Api 29.
Also DOES NOT work on Emulator Pixel 5 with Api 30.
Also DOES NOT work on testers devices on Pixel 6, 6 pro with Api 33 and their emulators with API 33.

I initially thought it could be because of API level differences, but the fact that testers are using the same config devices and still not hearing the notification sound in remote file case is confusing me a lot.

Any idea why this would be happening? I think its worth a discussion atleast.

Logically what I did so far is:

1. Get the soundUri from payload. Store the uri separately and trim uri and its extension out and create a channel name with just the soundName. My current use case allows me to create multiple channels.

```
            //Check if soundName is a remote sound file
            if (soundName != null) {

                // If soundname contains remote link, store it as a soundUrl and continue to trim soundName for channel Id and name
                if (soundName.contains("https")) {
                    soundUrl = soundName;
                    soundName = soundName.substring(soundName.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                }

                // Remove extension of sound file
                soundName = soundName.replaceFirst("[.][^.]+$", "");
            }
```

This below line assigns the soundUri smartly based on if the payload had an actual https url or a hardcoded file name from res > raw directory and based on that returns the uri.

`soundUri = getSoundUri(context, soundName, soundUrl);`

Inside getSoundUri function, if soundUrl exists, it does a Uri.parse and returns that uri

```
        if (soundUrl != null) {
            return Uri.parse(soundUrl);
        }
```

notification builder has high priority assigned. A trimmed version of codeblock shown below

```
            notificationBuilder
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
```

And at the end, there is channel creation code if the channel doesnt exist.

```
        private NotificationChannel createNotificationChannel(String channelId, String channelName, String channelDescription, Context context, Uri soundUri) {
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = null;
            AudioAttributes audioAttributes = getAudioAttributes();

            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
                notificationChannel.setDescription(channelDescription);
                notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
                notificationChannel.setShowBadge(isNotificationBadgingEnabled(context));
                **notificationChannel.setSound(soundUri, audioAttributes);**
            }

            return notificationChannel;
        }
```

Again, I have no problem creating channel and playing the sound which are locally stored, its just the remote sounds which are verified to be publicly available as .mp3 hosted on s3 / cloudflare seems to not work on my colleagues phones. It only works on one of my phone and one of my 4 emulators - Consistently!

For reasons still unknown (still scratching my head!), this works and does not work too! WHY!

---

---Update after checking logcat

The successfull ones look like this

> 22:57:13.517   598-598   NotificationHistory     system_process
> W  Attempted to add notif for locked/gone/disabled user 0 22:57:13.523
> 1681-1994  AiAiEcho                com.google.android.as
> W  SmartspaceNotificationPredictor no parser can handle this
> notification or notification is invalid 22:57:13.545   794-5516
> MediaHTTPService        com.android.systemui                 V
> MediaHTTPService(android.media.MediaHTTPService@ba5f5cc): Cookies:
> null 22:57:13.551   467-3266  NuPlayerDriver          mediaserver
> D  NuPlayerDriver(0xb400007b619991f0) created, clientPid(794)
> 22:57:13.556   221-221   hwservicemanager        hwservicemanager
> I  getTransport: Cannot find entry
> android.hardware.media.omx@1.0::IOmx/default in either framework or
> device VINTF

And the failure one looks like this:

> 23:00:58.514  1834-1834  NotificationHistory     system_server
> W  Attempted to add notif for locked/gone/disabled user 0 23:00:58.521
> 4241-5434  AiAiEcho                com.google.android.as
> W  SmartspaceNotificationPredictor no parser can handle this
> notification or notification is invalid 23:00:58.541  2237-28768
> MediaHTTPService        com.android.systemui                 V
> MediaHTTPService(android.media.MediaHTTPService@e875066): Cookies:
> null 23:00:58.543  1404-7155  ServiceManager          mediaserver
> W  Permission failure: android.permission.INTERNET from uid=10223
> pid=2237 23:00:58.543  1404-7155  MediaPlayerService      mediaserver
> E  Request requires android.permission.INTERNET 23:00:58.544
> 2237-28768 MediaPlayerNative       com.android.systemui
> E  Unable to create media player 23:00:58.544  2237-28768 MediaPlayer
> com.android.systemui                 V  resetDrmState:  mDrmInfo=null
> mDrmProvisioningThread=null mPrepareDrmInProgress=false
> mActiveDrmScheme=false 23:00:58.544  2237-28768 MediaPlayer
> com.android.systemui                 V  cleanDrmObj: mDrmObj=null
> mDrmSessionId=null 23:00:58.545  2237-28768 RingtonePlayer
> com.android.systemui                 W  error loading sound for
> https://app-remote-sounds.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/guitar.mp3
> java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed.: status=0x80000000
> at android.media.MediaPlayer.nativeSetDataSource(Native Method)
> at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1200)
> at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1187)
> at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1098)
> at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1023)
> at
> com.android.systemui.media.NotificationPlayer$CreationAndCompletionThread.run(NotificationPlayer.java:70)

Checked permission. I do have internet permission in Android Manifest file.

Also tried downloading the file to app's file directory & cache directory and getting that uri and assigning to channel.setSound. Even that didnt work. ‍♂️

Comment: Did you check the logcat? You may find something there I suppose

Comment: Thanks Sambhav! I missed checking the logcat somehow. Updating the post with what I found in logcat

Comment: Added what I found in post after a divider section.